# How to enable users to but goods from my android application?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay

If I want to create shopping app where the users can but virtual goods from the application, what should I use to implement something like this, does the android offers an API that can help to make it?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play In-App Billing API is what you are looking for.

The pages below are a good place to start:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html